# How can I update an installed stack package?

Tags: haskell-stack

I've installed a stack executable package with my own `stack.yaml` file that contains the following:

```
resolver: lts-8.2
packages:
- location:
    git: https://github.com/chrissound/ArchPackageCompareStats.git
    commit: c34b7dc5f08df92c6b6fb0cab0ac1d5b6b7568d4
- location:
    git: https://github.com/chrissound/ArchLinuxPkgStatsScraper.git
    commit: HEAD
```

The command I used was one of:

```
stack install --local-bin-path /server/ ArchPackageCompareStats
stack install -v ArchPackageCompareStats
```

Once I have updated the commit hashes in `stack.yaml`, how can I do an update of this package ?

Comment: Just run the same `stack install` commands as before?!

Comment: BTW the [stack docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#complex-package-locations-location) say: "it is highly recommended that you only use SHA1 values for a Git or Mercurial commit. Other values may work, but they are not officially supported, and may result in unexpected behavior (namely, stack will not automatically pull to update to new versions)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment by @sjakobi,the solution was to execute `stack install`.